# Erro: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify

Template:

```
<input type="text" v-model.trim="enterURL" placeholder="Enter URL here" @keyup.enter="Entered">
<v-btn icon @click.native.stop="Entered">
    <v-icon>send</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Script:

```
Entered(enterURL) {
    this.$emit('Entered', enterURL);
    let an_url = enterURL.target.value;
    if (this.layers_includes(an_url))
        return;

    axios.get(an_url).then(response => {
        let a_layer = new Layer();
        a_layer.enabled = true;
        a_layer.json = response.data;
        a_layer.url = an_url;

        this.layers.push(a_layer);
        L.geoJSON(a_layer.json).addTo(map);
        this.add_layer(a_layer);
    });
```

Ao pressionar 'Enter' funciona normalmente, mas, com o click do mouse no botão aparece esse erro no console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js?142d:57)
at dispatchXhrRequest (5:109)
at Promise (<anonymous>)
at xhrAdapter (5:12)
at dispatchRequest (26:52)
at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que quando usas o `@keyup.enter="Entered"` o método `Entered` recebe o evento como argumento e o `event.target` é o `input`. Aí fazes `let an_url = enterURL.target.value;` e tudo funciona. Mas quando usas `@click.native.stop="Entered"` aí o `event.target` já é outro, e não o `input`.

O melhor é dependeres dos eventos para saber quando o utilizador quer submeter, mas confiares o valor ao `v-model` e usares assim:

```
const an_url = this.enterURL;
```

O código todo seria:

```
Entered(enterURL) {
    this.$emit('Entered', enterURL);
    const an_url = this.enterURL;
    if (this.layers_includes(an_url)) return;

    axios.get(an_url).then(response => {
      const a_layer = new Layer();
      a_layer.enabled = true;
      a_layer.json = response.data;
      a_layer.url = an_url;

      this.layers.push(a_layer);
      L.geoJSON(a_layer.json).addTo(map);
      this.add_layer(a_layer);
  });
```